# Error while concatenating values from a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv file using python and displaying the record after asking the user to select an index and then I display all the records corresponding to the index number.

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_filepath, usecols=['userID', 'firstName', 'lastName'])
select_index = int(input("Enter the Index of Claimant: "))
data = df.loc[select_index, :]
print(data)

userID = data.userID
firstName = data.firstName
lastName = data.lastName
print(claimantID)
print(Claimant_FirstName)
print(Claimant_LastName)
```

The above code works perfectly fine and I am able to print the values.
Now I want to create a variable called as x and store userID + firstName + lastName .

If I do this I am getting error. What can be the issue.
Basically if I write

```
x = userID + firstName + lastName
```

I get the following error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('int64'), dtype('<U4')) -> None
```

Comment: It seems your `userID` is an integer. Try convert it to str before adding `str(userID) + ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with column types.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'userID': [1], 'firstName': ['a'], 'lastName':['b']})
data = df.loc[0, :]
userID = data.userID
firstName = data.firstName
lastName = data.lastName
#solution

x = str(userID) + firstName + lastName
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks... silly me couldn't figure out userID is int and I need to convert it first.